# What is running on my server every night?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014

My data disk queue is high every night at about 1:00 AM UTC. I did sql profiler trace and found that there are many queries running at the same time similar to these:

[image: profiler trace]

Can someone tell me what is going on there and how to stop or to control this?
Thanks in advance.

Version: SQL-Server 2014

**EDIT:**
I turned off the network, same issue. So, there is something inside SQL server.

Comment: Looks like some custom code that is processing indexes.  I cannot find any references to the code shown in your screen-capture on https://duckduckgo.com/?q=col.system_type_id+%3D+240+and+cols.user_type_id+%3D+128

Comment: In future, instead of posting a screenshot, you could simply copy-and-paste the T-SQL code into your answer, and "format as code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your profiler trace you should be able to see the Login and Host that the queries are coming from. I would then speak to your operations and/or development team to identify the application and function of the queries (or they should at least be able to point you in the direction of where you need to go/who you need to speak to).

Once you have that information you can see if the queries can be tuned in order to reduce the pressure on your disks.